# Implementing Salesforce SDK into EXISITING React Native Codebase

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, react-native

Everywhere I've look, including Salesforce Docs, it shows steps on how to create a **new** React Native project with the Salesforce SDK. I am having trouble finding any docs on how to get the Salesforce SDK setup in an **existing** React Native project.

Apologies in advance if this was an oversight on my end. This just seems like a very high use case and I was surprised to not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of the time, the 'upgrade' process to a new version of the Mobile SDK seems to involve creating a new project from scratch and copying your assets in. Seemed to go away for a while and then come back again.

You should be able to hook into the packages separately, it's not crazy hard to do for a native app but there could be some things different with the RN approach. If it was me I'd create that new project just to use as a reference point, and work out how it calls the login process etc. and take it from there, moving code from that new project over to yours as necessary.

The Mobile SDK isn't an officially supported product, and doesn't get half as much documentation as it deserves.

Comment: Thank you Matt. That sounds like the best approach and would also help me paint a good picture of everything going on behind the scenes so I could formulate my own doc.

Comment: Good luck with it - seems like there aren't a lot of people using the mobile SDK in anger, but everyone who is seems to encounter similar issues and is as helpful as they can be